# Title of tax type

Tags: taxes, income-tax, iran

What is the title of the tax type that a small business pays when they submit a tax return? Is it the income tax? Also, there are some small corporations that do not sell anything but offer services. What is the tax title of this group?

Comment: Also which country are you asking about would be important to know.

Comment: I am taking about Iranian tax system. When a small business like a clinical laboratory or a grocery store etc submit tax returns, their income is assessed by the tax officer and eventually they are handed over a bill on which the amount of levied tax is mentioned. The said bill is titled **business activity tax.** Which tax term in English can describe this? Thanks

Comment: You seem to know what it's called in Iran. Are you asking what it's called in the US?

Comment: Since they are to be presented in English-speaking countries, they should be equivalent or close to a term which is common in English.